# Обработка аварийного закрытия приложения

Tags: android, java

Иногда бывает, что программа закрывается (из-за какого-нибудь фатального эксепшена). Нельзя ли отлавливать этот момент в программе? Я хочу, чтобы если у пользователя произошел такой эксепшн, он автоматически репортился мне в трекер (API для этого есть и давно используется).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно ставить Хэндлеры для потоков [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) То есть по сути для главного потока приложения его наверно тоже можно назначать. А вобще рекомендую пользоваться сторонним сервисом [Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/) - он позволяет отлавливать ошибки в приложениях, которые уже размещены в маркете, собирает статистику и стэтрэйс этих ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Такая задача часто решается при помощи try и catch. в catch можно поместить отправку отчета. 
Вообще ещё необходимо у пользователя спрашивать, хочет ли он отправить репорт.
И предусмотреть отсутствие подключения к интернету в момент краша.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы есть.
И име ему [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Answer (score 0):

**ИМХО** использую [Critercism](https://www.crittercism.com/) вообще никаких нареканий. в отличии от **акры** ненужно заботится о переполнении гуглдока(если это еще не исправили) да и вообще юзабилити у них никакое.
**Crashlitycs** - использовал но кроме красивого дизаина и галимого плагина под еклипс ничего не увидел.

**но важно учитывать что не одно из вышеперечисленных решений не спасет вас если ошибка произошла в нативном коде**. тогда важно грамотно эту ошибочку ловить и что-то делать))).